# Ruby, greater than with variable above 1000 not working

Tags: ruby

here is my code

```
print("How far in metres are the people away from the spacecraft?")
people = gets.chomp
if people > "600" and (people !~ /\D/)
print ""
else
while !(people > "600" and (people !~ /\D/))
if people < "600" then
print"The people are too close to the launch site, make sure they are 600 metres away from it."
print "How far in metres are the people away from the spacecraft?"
people = gets.chomp
end
if !(people !~ /\D/)
puts "only enter numbers not letters. Please try again:"
people = gets.chomp
end
end
end
print ("The people are away from the launch site.")
```

I want the last line to appear when 'people' is above 600 but it also has to be a number. but the last line only appears if "people" is below 1000 above 600. Thanks for all the help. 
There are images below
[1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8FQb.png)

[789](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfE3s.png)

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but in most languages (that I know at least), Strings use a lexographical comparator to test if one string is greater or less than another. Since 1000 starts with a 1, it will be considered less that say, 600, which starts with a 6. Parse all the strings as numbers first, then compare.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're comparing `Strings` instead of `Integers`.

The strings are being compared alphabetically, so `"1000" < "700"` will be true, because `"1000"` appears before `"700"` when sorted alphabetically.

What you want is to convert the strings into integers before comparing them. Something like this:

```
people = "700"
if people.to_i > 600
  puts "It's greater than 600"
else
  puts "It's less than 600"
end
```

Notice the lack of quotes around `600`.

Answer (score 0):

### Cast as Integer

When you want to compare integers as numerical values, you need to convert the string stored in *people* first. Most people will tell you to use [String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-to_i), but that can be problematic and lead to excessive error-checking code. It's better to use [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer), which not only performs the cast but also raises an exception of the string can't be coerced. For example:

```
print 'Get integer: '

# Remove newlines and thousands separators, then cast as an integer.
people = Integer gets.chomp.delete ','

if people >= 600
  puts 'Far enough.'
else
  puts 'Not far enough.'
end
```

This way, if you enter a value such as `one thousand` or `x1000x` you'll get an exception like:

> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "x1000x"